# Strange Java error placement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Still working on the same project (Java-based shell) and tried to run it - and got a strange error. I was working with a single class that represents one of the commands, and, because of the fact that school computers have no compilers, I use [ideone](http://www.ideone.com). Anyway, I am getting an error and, while I have seen it before, the placement is really weird. The error:

```
Main.java:56: error: no enclosing instance of type LIST_Command is in scope
    public FAKE_CMD(int i) {this.msg = i;System.out.println(i);}
                           ^
```

Shouldn't this be in a place that is CALLING the constructor, or a static method of the class?

And here is the code (in its entirety, let me know what I should trim or edit it out yourself) Yes, this makes it an SSCCE.

```
package javashell.ver2.command;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class LIST_Command { /*extends Command*/
    public static Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

    public String description() {
        return "List all commands, their descriptions, or usages.";
    }

    public String usage() {
        return "list <cmds | desc | usage>";
    }

    public boolean runCmd(String[] cmdArgs, PrintStream output) {
        try {
            if (cmdArgs.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (cmdArgs.length > 0) {
                if (cmdArgs[0].equals("cmds")) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Command> cmd : /*main.Main.*/commands.entrySet()) {
                        output.println(cmd.getKey());
                    }
                }
                else if (cmdArgs[0].equals("desc")) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Command> cmd : /*main.Main.*/commands.entrySet()) {
                        output.println(cmd.getValue().description());
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        commands.put("test1", new FAKE_CMD(1));
        commands.put("test2", new FAKE_CMD(2));
        new LIST_Command().runCmd(new String[] {"cmds"}, System.out);
    }

    abstract class Command {
        public abstract String usage();
        public abstract String description();
        public abstract boolean runCmd(String[] cmdArgs, PrintStream output);
    }

    static class FAKE_CMD extends Command {
        int msg;
        public FAKE_CMD(int i) {
            this.msg = i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        public String usage() {
            return "usagetest" + msg;
        }
        public String description() {
            return "descriptiontest" + msg;
        }
        public boolean runCmd(String[] cmdArgs, PrintStream output) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess you have a `{` or `}` out of place somewhere, but the code is too poorly formatted to tell for sure.

Comment: I really want to know how a school can ask students to produce code without providing them with the basic development tools.

Comment: @Stefano It isn't for school - it is a personal project that I work on during free periods at school. Also, they just installed Win7 on the computers and havent gotten around to reinstalling the programs

Comment: @HotLicks, how is it poorly formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `FAKE_CMD` need to call its superclass' (`Command`'s) constructor. However, since the superclass is not `static`, Java has no way of instantiate a superclass instance before constructing a `FAKE_CMD`.

Comment: This explains the answer better than Marko's so this will be accepted once I have the chance. It explains the location of the error too.

Answer (score 3):

`Command` is an inner class, which doesn't seem to make sense since it is contained in a class that should be its subclass. Anyway, that is the cause of your error: regardless of whether `FAKE_CMD` is itself static or not, it needs an enclosing instance of `LIST_Command` since it extends `Command`.

Note a possible subtlety in Java's terminology: *inner class* means a *non-static nested class*, therefore it implies the need for an enclosing instance.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

EDIT: If I make Command static too, will that fix the issue?

Comment: the reason it is all in one class is because IDEOne (A bad site but the only option) can only work with one class at a time. This was just to test it out.

Comment: You can still get away with it if you make `Command` the top-level class, and others must be its nested classes.

Comment: Not fully since there's no way for a subclass to contain its own superclass. So you won't be able to make `LIST_Command` extend `Command`.

Comment: @NickHartley AFIK, IDEOne limits you to one source "file". You can still have more than one top-level class in a file; just be sure that only one top-level class is declared `public`. Also, why is this your only option? Do you not have some way to download a free text editor or idE?

Comment: @Code-Guru I forgot that you can do that... This is my only option because the school computers on which I was working when I found this did not have any IDEs installed and I could not install these.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, ok. I deleted my comment.